# How to make dynamically generated captcha code of fixed length

Tags: jquery

I am generating the capthca code dynamically as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function() {

DrawCaptcha();

});


   function DrawCaptcha() {
     var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var f = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' ' + f;
     $(".captha-img")[0].innerHTML = code;
   }
```

All this is working fine .

But right now , the issue i am facing is that ,

I needed a Capthcha code of exactly 6 digits , but **sometimes** the capthacha that is being geenerated is more than 6 digits .

Could  you please let me know how to fix this ??

http://jsfiddle.net/2yXsL/383/

Comment: change Math.ceil to Math.floor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Math.ceil` to `Math.floor` it will always return you 6 digits:

```
   function DrawCaptcha() {
     var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var e = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var f = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' ' + f;
     $(".captha-img")[0].innerHTML = code;
   }
```

The problem with your code was, Whenever `Math.random()` was returning you anything above `9.0` it was rounding it off to 10. That's the reason why you were seeing more than 6 digits at times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.substring()` method as shown :-

```
  function DrawCaptcha() {
     var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var f = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10) + '';
     var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' ' + f;
     $(".captha-img")[0].innerHTML = code.substring(0,12);
   }
```

Above code will provide a fix 6 digit number as capthcha code.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2yXsL/384/)